# XPath to merge child node attributes with parent

Tags: xpath

I'm looking for an xpath expression to merge the child node attributes with the parrent.

```
<player uni="04" name="John Doe" gp="1" gs="1" pos="G"> 
<stats fgm="0" fga="3" fgm3="0" fga3="1" ftm="2" fta="2" tp="2" blk="0" stl="0" ast="0" min="23" oreb="2" dreb="2" treb="4" pf="2" tf="0" to="3" dq="0"></stats> 
</player>
```

I tried the following and it's close but the child node is still within the parent.

```
//team[1]/player[@*] | ../stats[@*]
```

This is what i get:

```
<player uni="03" name="John Doe"  gp="1" gs="1" pos="G">
<stats fgm="0" fga="3" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="10" fta="10" tp="10" blk="0" stl="1" ast="1" min="33" oreb="2" dreb="2" treb="4" pf="2" tf="0" to="1" dq="0"> </stats>
</player>
```

This is what i want:

```
<player uni="03" name="John Doe"  gp="1" gs="1" pos="G" fgm="0" fga="3" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="10" fta="10" tp="10" blk="0" stl="1" ast="1" min="33" oreb="2" dreb="2" treb="4" pf="2" tf="0" to="1" dq="0"></player>
```

Comment: XPath allows you to select nodes and values from input source but so far it is not able to create new nodes, i.e. a new element node with attributes from different elements; for that you can use XQuery or XSLT.

Comment: For version 4 of XPath there is some debate to introduce "node constructor" functions, see https://github.com/qt4cg/qtspecs/issues/573 and https://www.saxonica.com/~mike/builder.html. But at least from those who do XQuery anyway there seems to be some doubt whether there is a need to have XPath functions for node constructor expressions XQuery already has.